# using multiple If then statements in python corectly

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to write a program where a shortest path is found between nodes in a list such as the one below. The nodes are A, B, C, D and the path length between them is listed as "A|B|1" or "B|D|9". The program is supposed to iterate through the paths and find the shortest path from first to last node, if the path exists. The part where I'm stuck is the very last `for` statement of the code (even though this code is not final and I still need to work on it). This last "for" statement crashes my python shell and then I have to restart it. Maybe an infinite loop?

In this statement I am trying to compare values in the dictionary i created to values to the `nextpath` variable which is continuously updated with values from the dictionary. For example if AB is in `nextpath`, it should be compared to other values in the dictionary (eg: BD) and since AB contains B, this path can link to BD. The problem is when I try to do this the program crashes and i=I'm stuck.

```
# input given to code "4","A","B","C","D","A|B|1","B|D|9","B|C|3","C|D|4"
import re

def WeightedPath(strarr): 
    exclude2=[',','"',"|"]
    strarr=list(s for s in strarr if s not in exclude2)

    numnodes = int(strarr[0])+1
    actualnodes=strarr[1:int(strarr[0])+1]
    end = len(strarr)
    print "____________________________________________________"
    paths = strarr[numnodes:end]
    paths2=""
    for i in paths:
        paths2+=i
    paths3=re.split('(\d+)',paths2)
    paths3=paths3[0:-1] #last item was empty quotes so i got rid of it
    print "paths",paths3

    paths_2=[] # second item behind weight
    paths_1=[] # first item behind weight
    pathsnum=[] # actual weight of path
    for i in paths3:  
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            paths_2.append(paths3[paths3.index(i)-2])
            paths_1.append(paths3[paths3.index(i)-1])
            pathsnum.append(paths3[paths3.index(i)])

    dictname=paths3[0::2] #names of dict items
    dictionary=dict(zip(dictname,pathsnum))

    print "names of nodes: ",actualnodes
    print "dictionary: ",dictionary

    fromnode= actualnodes[0]
    tonode= actualnodes[-1]

    tohere=[]
    for i in dictionary.keys():
        if tonode in i:
            tohere.append(i)     

    nextpath=[]
    for i in dictionary.keys():
        if fromnode in i:
            nextpath.append(i)

    for i in dictionary.keys():
        if i not in nextpath:
            for j in nextpath:
                if j[0] in i or j[1] in i:
                    nextpath.append(i)



    print "nextpath",nextpath


print WeightedPath(raw_input())
```

Comment: Why not model this as a graph and apply dijikstra?

Comment: i'm not familiar with that method...i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

You may not modify a dictionary/list you are iterating over.

```
for j in nextpath:
    if j[0] in i or j[1] in i:
        nextpath.append(i)
```

The result of those line is undefined if the condition evaluates to `True` at least once. Either make a copy or use indices, depending on what you want.

This will iterate on whatever is in `nextpath` when you start looping:

```
for j in list(nextpath):
    if j[0] in i or j[1] in i:
        nextpath.append(i)
```

This will also include added elements:

```
index = 0
while index < len(nextpath):
    j = nextpath[index]
    if j[0] in i or j[1] in i:
        nextpath.append(i)
```

You may also have other issues in your code, I did not actually check the logic, I'm just pointing this common mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the while loop you suggested and the same freezing of python happens. I'm assuming because the loop does the same thing....

Comment: Yes, the mistake my answer fixes should not freeze your python, so it's possibly not the one you were after. But there was no way to know without fixing it first. That's one less to worry about in your debugging process. Good luck.